# Click on one div and make Angular template open in another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-route

I want to be able to click on the anchor in the **#leftDiv** and make the UI router template open in the **#rightDiv**. So, when I click on **Hello Plunker 1** in the **#leftDiv**, I want **peopleOne.html** to open in the **#rightDiv**. When I click on **Hello Plunker 2**, I want **peopleTwo.html** to replace **peopleOne.html** in the **#rightDiv**.

Here is a Plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/T8RTgea8VccA9mdBABGC?p=preview

Can someone provide insight into why this is not working.

**Script.js**

```
var Delivery = angular.module('Delivery', ['ui.router']);

angular
    .module('Delivery')

.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');        

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/Delivery',
            views: {
                'view': {
                            templateUrl: 'Delivery.html',
                        },
            },
        })

        .state('peopleOne', {
                url: '/peopleOne',
                parent: 'home',
                views: {
                    'view@': {
                    templateUrl: 'peopleOne.html'
                    }
                },
            })

        .state('peopleTwo', {
                url: '/peopleTwo',
                parent: 'home',
                views: {
                    'view@': {
                    templateUrl: 'peopleTwo.html'
                    }
                },
            })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems I've noticed:

First, put a `console.log` after the $stateProvider configuration calls to setup your routes. You will see that this code is never even called. Your angular app is not quite set up properly. You are using `dat-ng-app` in the index template, when you should be using `ng-app`. Otherwise angular is never actually used.

The next issue is in your `$stateProvider` configuration. I am not sure which documentation you are following, but your configurations for the states should look something like this:

```
    # Set the default state
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home')

    # Configures home, peopleOne, and peopleTwo states
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: '/home',
          templateUrl: 'home.html'
        })
        .state('peopleOne', {
          url: '/peopleOne',
          templateUrl: 'peopleOne.html',
          parent: 'home'
        })
        .state('peopleTwo', {
          url: '/peopleTwo',
          templateUrl: 'peopleTwo.html',
          parent: 'home'
        })
```

Finally, when actually creating the links in your template, I find it easier to use the `ui-sref` tag, which allows you to create a link based on a state name. So a link to the `peopleOne` state would look like this: `<a ui-sref="peopleOne"></a>`.

I've attached a plunker based off your original code

https://plnkr.co/edit/NazuoFoDOa3VGR6smoyH